# Map a string get length of each word and append to a new with an condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add any word that has a length greater than 5 characters, but I don't know how to add the words to it.

```
s = 'This sentence is a string'
l = list(map(len, s.split()))
l.sort()
w=[]
for i in l:
    if (i >= 5):
        w.append(i)
        print(w)

output [6]
             [6, 8]
```

I can get the size of each word in the sentence, but linking the length to the word itself has been hard as it is between string and integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a list-comprehension to do that:

```
s = 'This sentence is a string'
words = [w for w in s.split() if len(w) > 5]
print(words) # ==> ['sentence', 'string']
```

Alternatively, a `filter` with a `lambda` could be used as well:

```
s = 'This sentence is a string'
words = list(filter(lambda w: len(w) > 5, s.split()))
print(words) # ==> ['sentence', 'string']
```

Comment: I actually like the list-comprehension, but it was an exercised I got stuck with as I am immigrating from java to python. Thanks a lot for your help Mr Geek